# Why can't I mmap more than 1G hugepages?

Tags: c, linux, mmap, huge-pages

```
pqy@3500X ~/projects/hp/build $ cat ../main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    void *addr = mmap(NULL, n*1024*1024*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0);
    if(addr == -1){
        perror("mmap");
    }
    return 0;
}
pqy@3500X ~/projects/hp/build $ cat /proc/meminfo |grep -i huge
AnonHugePages:   1058816 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:     36864 kB
HugePages_Total:       4
HugePages_Free:        4
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
Hugetlb:         4194304 kB
pqy@3500X ~/projects/hp/build $ ./hp 1
pqy@3500X ~/projects/hp/build $ ./hp 2
mmap: Cannot allocate memory
pqy@3500X ~/projects/hp/build $ ./hp 3
mmap: Cannot allocate memory
pqy@3500X ~/projects/hp/build $ ./hp 4
mmap: Invalid argument
```

I have 4 free 1G hugepages, and I would like to mmap all to my process. But in my test program, I can only mmap 1G successfully. Larger value throws "Cannot allocate memory" or "Invalid argument", which is confusing to me. Any trap here?

Comment: Hint: compile with `clang -fsanitize=undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `n` variable is an `int`, which is 32-bit wide in Linux in x86_64. This means values of `2` or higher overflow.

In practice, `2` and `3` are yielding negative numbers which get interpreted as huge 64-bit unsigned values (so the allocation fails), and `4` yields exactly `0` (so the argument is invalid).

Comment: In particular, it's the multiplication `n*1024*1024*1024` which is done as `int` and therefore overflows.  The easiest fix might be `(size_t)n * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`, or `n * 1024UL * 1024UL * 1024UL`.